# Un mot français pour "to smirk" dans un dialogue vidéo

Tags: traduction, anglais, verbes, demande-de-mot

Existe-il un verbe en un seul mot pour dire *to smirk* en français ? Parce que la plupart des traducteurs me sortent des trucs long pas possible comme :

> sourire d'un air satisfait [(source)](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/to+smirk)

Mais c'est beaucoup trop long, on passe de 5 lettres en anglais à 5 mots en français.

**EDIT (2016-07-06)**

Dans le contexte, par exemple, si l'on doit suivre le rythme d'une vidéo ou deux anglophones discutent à propos d'un événement passé.

> [...]
>
> - And what he did after that ? *(Et qu'a-t-il fait après ça ?)*
> - He smirked. *<-- (Texte à traduire)*
>
> [...]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

En dehors de ***[ricaner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ricaner)***, qui n'a pas tout à fait le même sens, il n'y a pas de verbe correspondant à *smirk* en français, on utilise le nom *sourire* que l'on qualifie :

> - petit sourire narquois,
> - sourire méprisant,
> - rictus [auto-]satisfait (ou d'autosatisfaction),
> - sourire moqueur,
> - sourire suffisant,
> - rictus, sourire ironique,
> - sourire accrocheur,
> - sourire en coin...

... ensuite on peut le fait précéder du verbe *avoir* ou *faire*, ou le faire suivre d'un verbe qui le manifeste :

- Un sourire narquois apparut sur son visage quand ...
- ..., phrase qu'il conclut d'un sourire en coin.
- ...

Comme le suggère le commentaire de *[qoba](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/10519/qoba)* on peut supprimer la notion de sourire ou de rictus lorsqu'il est sous-entendu, peut-être que le `!` devient alors nécessaire :

- ... dit-il narquois / ironique / moqueur / satisfait / méprisant !

Pour une traduction fidèle au sens ou à l'ambiance du texte original, la transposition peut nécessiter plus de syllabes et avoir la même interprétation dans l'autre langue, les rythmes ne sont pas obligatoirement les mêmes pour évoquer les mêmes émotions ou sentiments.

*Smirk* n'est pas actuellement un anglicisme que l'on peut intégrer dans le langage courant.

---

***Traduction possible du dialogue***

N.B. :
1 - pour une version doublée en français : sept syllabes pour la question, trois pour la réponse.
2 - si l'on veut économiser du texte pour un sous-titrage, on n'est pas obligé de traduire le *that* en *ça* ou en *cela*.
3 - s'il faut 'coller' à l'image, une transposition fidèle sera plus pertinente qu'un mot à mot basique.
Un traducteur est aussi un interprète, ce qui est un art à part entière qui doit rendre le sensible vivant ; il peut être plus à même de créer l'ambiance correspondante dans sa langue que le dialoguiste ne peut le faire dans le contexte originel.

Plutôt soutenu, mais reste oral :

> - Que fit-il après tout ça ?
> - Il's'moqua !

Si l'on veut insister sur la vanité du personnage :

> - Qu'a-t-il fait après cela ?
> - Le frimeur !

Argot :

> - L'a fait quoi après ce mec ?
> - le fierrot / le malin !

**Complété le 20 avril 2021**

> - L'a fait quoi après ce mec ?
> - … ***il était goguenard** !*

Quelques possibilités parmi toutes sortes d'attitudes qui sous-entendent un sourire narquois, méprisant...

Comment: Le problème, c'est que j'essais de faire une traduction en suivant un rythme, je ne peux pas me permettre d'ajouter une phrase à quelque chose qui se disait en une syllabe en version originale.

Comment: @Carlos2W -- Si c'est pour un exercice 'encadré', *ricaner* pourrait convenir pour deux ou trois des propositions faites dans ma réponse. Il m'arrive d'écouter LGL http://www.france5.fr/emissions/la-grande-librairie ; un auteur anglais (ou américain, connu, mais j'ai oublié son nom, qui vit souvent France ) aime relire son traducteur et y découvrir l'enrichissement que l'interprétation et la transposition apportent... c'est alors *l'art de traduire*.

Comment: Suivre quel rythme?

Comment: @Carlos2W on pourrait faire de meilleures suggestions avec plus de contexte. Par exemple les adjectifs "suffisant" ou "narquois" peuvent suffire par eux-mêmes, sans "sourire", selon le contexte. On peut aussi dire "l'air narquois", "l'air suffisant" entre deux virgules pour traduire l'idée de "with a smirk". Suggérerais de donner un peu plus de contexte dans votre question.

Comment: @Lambie -- Le rythme de la prosodie (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosodie)  qui exprime beaucoup plus que les mots eux-mêmes, d'où les différentes interprétations théâtrales d'une même pièce... ce qui révèle le talent (ou l'absence de talent) des acteurs qui ne sont jamais que les *interprètes* de l'auteur,

Comment: @cl-r Attention car le verbe anglais "to grin" a une signification similaire a plusieurs de vos définitions

Comment: @Blue_Elephant De ce que j'ai comprit de http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=to+grin  *to grin* se traduit par *sourire*, que l'on peut qualifier selon le contexte, et vous y trouverez "satisfied grin" -- Il peut donc y avoir recouvrement en fonction du choix des adjectifs choisis ; *smirt* induit la notion de mépris d l'autre.

Comment: J'ai édité ma question pour y ajouter le contexte très brièvement. J'ai peur que les trop longues réponses casse le rythme de la vidéo par leur longueur. *Ricaner*, dans ce cas, ne serait peut-être pas le plus approprié, étant lié de près à **rire** et plus tôt, on ne vit pas le personnage rire, mais bien *smirk*. :/

Comment: Vu le contexte (introduit par "qu'a-t-il fait après ?") une traduction par un nom serait meilleure à mon avis, par exemple "un sourire narquois" ou "un sourire en coin"

Answer (score 0):

Si l'on peut permettre des mots peu fréquents:

> - Qu'a-t-il fait après cela ?
> - Des lazzis, des brocards, des quolibets

Sinon:

> - Qu'a-t-il fait après cela ?
> - Le bouffon